# spring integration handle exception after splitter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am new to Spring integration.

If I have a request coming in with batch payload(json array)
and I use splitter to split it into jsonobject, 
and then I do validation.

If some of the validation failed and throw exception into error channel.

How can I make a response to client indicating some of the jsObject failed 
and some works?

not sure handler at errorChannel gonna help since the validation result comes async into errorChannel.

And if I call the gateway like this, how can I construct a validation Result for the whole payload with validation status for each jsObject inside?

`Future<validationResult> r = gateway.send(...)`

(gateway just forward the request to following endpoint right away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a look into `Aggregator` EIP: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html, http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator.

So, all your objects are send for the validation and their results (good or bad) send to the `<aggregator>` to build a single `validationResult` for the reply to that gateway.

Comment: thanks for the help. I did some test, there is one problem with this is that, after splitter, the message will be assigned with a correlation_id, for future grouping in aggregator. But the problems is if one of the element after splitter throws exception, it will create a new message and the correlation_id will be lost. Aggregator will complain "CorrelationStrategy is failing". Do you have experience with solving this?

Comment: When some downstream component throws exception, it is wrapped to the `MessagingException` with the `failedMessage` property. That is exactly a hook where you can extract original headers, including required `sequenceNumber`, `sequenceSize`, `correlationId`. Actually, I'd copy all those headers to a newly created message before sending to the aggregator.

Comment: Yes I would also do that, but I didn't catch the failedMessage property. I tried a int:service-activator to connect the error channel, and call back method take Message<?> message as input, I print the payload and the header of message, it has no failedMessage properties... not sure which part went wrong.

Comment: `errorChannel` receives `ErrorMessage`s. The `payload` there is exactly `MessagingException` and so on.

Comment: Let's continue discussion exactly in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213217/spring-integration-throw-exception-with-correlation-id !