# spring integration throw exception with correlation id

Tags: rest, exception, spring-integration, message

I have a problem with handling batch processing with spring integration.
Normally After splitter, all the element(Message) will be assigned with a correlation_id for future grouping in Aggregator, but the problem is that when there is a exception thrown when processing the element(Message), a MeesageException will be created and the correlation_id is lost.

I can use HeaderEnricher to add the correlation_id but it cannot be hard coded I assume, other wise if there are multiple requests come together, things gonna be grouped together and everything will be messed up. 
The root cause is when throwing exception spring integration will not attach the correlation_id... and it seems never be re-gained...

Aggregator will complain about "CorrelationStrategy is failing"

How to deal with this?
Let's say my expectation could be 10 datapoint in batch, and I want to give response for {failed 5, pass 5} or sth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException` is thrown by the Spring Integration components, it is typically contains a `failedMessage` property to indicate a `requestMessage` which caused the problem.

All the required headers for you (`correlationId`, `sequenceNumber`, `sequenceSize` etc.) are exactly in that property.

If you are going to send the error-handling result back to the aggregator you should copy headers from that `failedMessage` to newly created message.

The Framework doesn't do that by default because a `ErrorMessage` is fully separate flow and there is no guaranty that it always comes back to the main flow, e.g. for aggregation.

See more information in the [Error Handling chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler).

Comment: I think I got this! I tried a int:service-activator to connect the error channel, and call back method take Message<?> message as input, it actually in the message.getpayload.getFailedMessage()

Comment: Really appreciate your help!

Comment: failedMessage also include a replyChannel which seems different from the original channel when I print the header and comparing with other valid work flow. Should I exclude it or I can just dump all the things from failedMessage back into headers?

Comment: when I aggregate the error message with the valid branch, I can build a Customized Result, but I am getting the "Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply" and gateway.publish() return a null result. which cause error. Is there something I missed?

Comment: It depends of your logic. If you are really intended to fully replace error with a new valid message, you definitely should copy all of them from `failedMessage` .

Comment: M-m-m. I think you have to override `errorChannel` or use different approach to try-catch exception. Looks like a different SO question to investigate your logic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256191/spring-integration-errorchannel-error-handle this one