# Spring integration errorChannel, error handle

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-integration

Scenario could be: my expectation could be 10 datapoint in batch, and I want to give response for {failed 5, pass 5} or sth.

my logic is to split the batch into data element and do validation.

successful validation will send to aggreagtor,

failed validation will throw error and pick up by error channel.

recipient-list-router take the errorChannel as inputChannel and 2 filter connect to it, the purpose is to filter some type of error to send response directly(eception unrelated to user input - server error or etc) and some type of client side error will go to aggregator to build response.

Is any problem with the logic?
My problem is I keep getting "Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply" when build up the Result using service-activator after aggregator. this service-activator connect to replyChannel and it seems like there are some message already sent to this channel?

I checked my integration work flow only this service-activator and server error branch after "error filter" connect to replyChannel(but the handle is never called.)

Something wrong? BTW, can recipient-list-router or other type of endpoint connect to errorChannel? or it has to be service-activator as what I saw in all the example online?(but they are really simple example..)

Sample XML

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="someGateway" default-request-channel="splitChannel" error-channel="errorChannel"  default-reply-channel="replyChannel" async-executor="MyThreadPoolTaskExecutor"/>

<int:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="transformChannel" method="split">
    <bean class="Splitter" />
</int:splitter>

<int:transformer id="transformer" input-channel="transformChannel" method="transform" output-channel="aggregateChannel">
    <bean class="Transformer"/>  // this may throw the validation error (filter_ErrorType_1), if it cannot transform
</int:transformer>

<int:aggregator id="aggregator"
    input-channel="aggregateChannel"
    output-channel="createAnswerChannel"
    method="aggregate">
    <bean class="MyAggregator" />
</int:aggregator>

<int:recipient-list-router id="myErrorRouter" input-channel="errorChannel">
    <int:recipient channel="filter_ErrorType_1"/> 
    <int:recipient channel="filter_ErrorType_2"/> 
    <int:recipient channel="filter_ErrorType_3"/> 
</int:recipient-list-router>

<int:filter input-channel="filter_ErrorType_1" output-channel="aggregateChannel" method="accept"></int:filter>
<int:filter input-channel="filter_ErrorType_2" output-channel="createErrorAnswerChannel" method="accept"></int:filter>
<int:filter input-channel="filter_ErrorType_3" output-channel="createErrorAnswerChannel" method="accept"></int:filter>

<int:service-activator input-channel='createErrorAnswerChannel' output-channel="replyChannel" method='buildError'>
    <bean class="AnswerBuilder"/>
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel='createAnswerChannel' output-channel="replyChannel" method='build'>
    <bean class="AnswerBuilder"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

Follow up:

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="someGateway" default-request-channel="splitChannel" error-channel="errorChannel"  default-reply-channel="replyChannel" async-executor="MyThreadPoolTaskExecutor"/>

<int:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="transformChannel" method="split">
    <bean class="Splitter" />
</int:splitter>

<int:transformer id="transformer1" input-channel="toTransformer1" method="transform" output-channel="toTransformer2">
    <bean class="Transformer1"/>  // this may throw the validation error (filter_ErrorType_1), if it cannot transform
</int:transformer>

<int:transformer id="transformer2" input-channel="toTransformer2" method="transform" output-channel="toTransformer3">
    <bean class="Transformer2"/>  // this may throw the validation error (filter_ErrorType_2), if it cannot transform
</int:transformer>

<int:transformer id="transformer3" input-channel="toTransformer3" method="transform" output-channel="aggregateChannel">
    <bean class="Transformer3"/>  // this may throw the validation error (filter_ErrorType_3), if it cannot transform
</int:transformer>

???
// seems like you are proposing to have one gateway for each endpoint that may throw error.
// but in this case, take transfomer 1 for example, I cannot output the gateway directly to aggregate channel since for valid data it has to go to transformer 2
// but the failed message throwed by the error handler cannot pass transformer 2 because of afterall this is a error message not a valid data for transformer 2
// <int:service-activator input-channel="toTransformer1" output-channel="toTransformer2" ref="gateway1"/>

// <int:gateway id="gateway1" default-request-channel="toTransformer1" error-channel="errorChannel1"/>

// <int:transformer id="transformer" input-channel="toTransformer1" method="transform">
//     <bean class="Transformer"/>  // this may throw the validation error (filter_ErrorType_1), if it cannot transform
// </int:transformer>

// how to deal with this problem?




<int:service-activator input-channel='createErrorAnswerChannel' output-channel="replyChannel" method='buildError'>
    <bean class="AnswerBuilder"/>
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator input-channel='createAnswerChannel' output-channel="replyChannel" method='build'>
    <bean class="AnswerBuilder"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

I actually have complicated logic inside but I use transformer 123 to represent here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't clear. Please,be sure in the future provide more concrete info. Some config and StackTrace or logs are useful, too.

I guess that you have in the beginning of your flow `<gateway>` with configured `error-channel`. That's why you are receiving `Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply`.

But I can't be sure, because there is no those words in your question. Right?

You can't rely on the `errorChannel` header there and come back for the `reply` eventually because the `errorChannel` header in case of Gateway is the same as `replyChannel`, and it is `TemporaryReplyChannel` - one-shot-usage channel and only for `receive()` operation.

Since we don't have any configuration or code from you we can't help you properly.

I suppose you need a middle-flow `gateway` via `service-activator`:

```
<service-activator id="gatewayTestService" input-channel="inputChannel" 
            output-channel="outputChannel" ref="gateway"/>

<gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="requestChannel" error-channel="myErrorChannel"/>
```

or `<chain>` with `<gateway>` to perform validation and catch errors only there and return a desired reply for failures. That `service-activator` will be able to send them all to the `<aggregator>` afterward. In this case the `<aggregator>` can reply back to the gateway properly.

**EDIT**

1. `errorChannel` is a name for default global bean to catch any error messages from any Integration place. See more info in the http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler.

So, that name is fully bad for your use case , because that `myErrorRouter` is going to handle ALL the errors!

2. The `<int:recipient-list-router>` sends message to all its recipients if it passes a `selector` or if there is no [`selector`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter).
3. You don't need `default-reply-channel` on the `<gateway>` if it isn't `publish-subscribe`. You can just rely on the `replyChannel` header, which works if there is no `output-channel` [defined](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-default-reply-channel).
4. What I'm talking about `<service-activator>` and `<gateway>` is pretty straight forward in front of your `<transformer>` after `<splitter>`:

   ```
   <int:service-activator input-channel="transformChannel" 
               output-channel="aggregateChannel" ref="gateway"/>

   <int:gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="transformChannel" error-channel="validationErrorChannel"/>

   <int:transformer id="transformer" input-channel="transformChannel" method="transform">
       <bean class="Transformer"/>  // this may throw the validation error (filter_ErrorType_1), if it cannot transform
   </int:transformer>
   ```

So, `splitter` sends items to the `service-activator`. That one proceeds with the message to the `gateway` around `transformer` with custom `error-channel` exactly for one item. The `transformer` answers to the `replyChannel` exactly to that previous `gateway`. If it throws some Exception, it is handled by the `validationErrorChannel` process. Which should reply with some compensation message. That message is bubbled to the `service-activator`. Finally `service-activator` sends a result to the `aggregateChannel`. And it is black box for the `service-activator` if validation was good or not.

Hope that helps a bit.

**EDIT2**

I'm disappointed that you haven't accepted my advises in your code, but nevertheless that is how I see it:

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="someGateway" default-request-channel="splitChannel"
             async-executor="MyThreadPoolTaskExecutor" />

<int:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="transformChannel" method="split">
    <bean class="Splitter" />
</int:splitter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="validateChannel" output-channel="aggregateChannel"
      ref="validateGateway"/>

<gateway id="validateGateway" default-request-channel="toTransformer1" error-channel="myErrorChannel"/>

<chain input-channel="toTransformer1">
    <int:transformer method="transform">
        <bean class="Transformer1" />
    </int:transformer>
    <int:transformer method="transform">
        <bean class="Transformer2" />
    </int:transformer>
    <int:transformer method="transform">
        <bean class="Transformer3" />
    </int:transformer>
</chain>


<int:service-activator input-channel="myErrorChannel" method="buildError">
    <bean class="AnswerBuilder" />
</int:service-activator>

<int:aggregator id="aggregator"
                input-channel="aggregateChannel"
                output-channel="createAnswerChannel"
                method="aggregate">
    <bean class="MyAggregator" />
</int:aggregator>

<int:service-activator input-channel='createAnswerChannel' method='build'>
    <bean class="AnswerBuilder" />
</int:service-activator>
```

Pay attention, how I *chain* transformers. So, you have one gateway for all your transformers and any error on any of them will be thrown to the gateway for error handling on the `myErrorChannel`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, yes I configure my <gateway> with error-channel = "errorChannel", I will update this question later with xml snippet.

Comment: is it possible that the reply channel and the error channel are the same, so when error occur, exception will be sent to errorChannel and this is marked as received, but I continue to do processing after that(forward the error message to other endpoints for processing) and when I send the aggregator result to reply channel, it will complain about sth already received?  Does it means create a errorChannel different from replyChannel at gateway will help? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, that is a case. They are really the same object. Sorry if I wasn't clear. The `error- channel` on gateway works only after received a message in `replyChannel` or `errorChannel` headers, which are the same object. You should understand that `replyChannel` and `errorChannel` is `TemporaryReplyChannel` for only one message and only for one reply.

Comment: I can confirm that error handling flow from gateway uses its own `TemporaryReplyChannel`, so we really can return a compensation message from there, but that doesn't help in case of multi errors like your validation use-case. That's why I suggest you to wrap each item to intermediate gateway for its own closed error handling scope. Then the original gateway won't be affected and aggregator will do its good work for reply too!

Comment: I am a little bit confused about how to wire them using the service-activator and gateway you answered previously, can you modify the upper sample xml to give me some idea and update it in your answer to give me some idea? I don't know where to put my transformer in this case, and how to wire the error of this scope to my recipient-list-router to do filter. I am new to SI, thanks!

Comment: If this is not too trouble for you.

Comment: See an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: For your new edit, after "validationErrorChannel" do I need to add another transformer to handle this error message to put the failedMessage property back into the header in order to let Aggregator recognize the grouping logic? It this is the case, in this header, what will be the header of "replyChannel"? will it be the 1st gateway replyChannel? Is it ok?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. The `service-activator` does the trick for you. You should just return from that sub-flow a desired `payload`. The `service-activator` properly copies all the headers to the outputMessage.

Comment: Seems like I cannot get response, dont know whether it is the reply channel got messed up for multiple channel. Right now I only testing valid data, and I can see my aggregator got correct amount messages, I can build the Answer, but not getting reply from client. Is there somewhere else to be configured? Or where to check to target shotting?

Comment: Well, you have to share your config and maybe logs on the matter. I think some replacement of that existing code would be enough

Comment: Could you please to answer the follow up I edit above? Really appreciate your patient

Comment: Look at an `EDIT2` in my answer.

Comment: I accepted it, I was about to do the same thing. But I also have recipient-list-router for some outbound messaging before the aggregator, I am not sure can recipient-list-router go inside chain also?

Comment: It can if one of recipients returns to the `replyChannel` and all others are dead-end. With the gateway you can have only one reply. Treat it as `return` of regular Java code. You can have only one output from the method invocation. Isn't it? So, I have to understand the premise of your recipient-list-router. Maybe we could start a new SO thread for that purpose?

Comment: this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358953/sring-integration-recipient-list-router-inside-chain thx